# How to correctly notify in QQmlListProperty properties?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qproperty, qqmllistproperty

Whenever I was creating a `Q_PROPERTY` for later use in Qml I always created a notify signal to tell qml that data changed and needs to be reevaluated.

Now having a `Q_PROPERTY` of the type `QQmlListProperty<T>` how can I signalize that an item has been modified, added or removed?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you need to populate the list from QML ?

Comment: Yes. I will also need to add items on button click. The list could be changed from C++ or from Qml. I want it to work in both directions.

Comment: If it's for a model belonging in your c++ logic layer, use a `QAbstractItemModel` to expose it. It has signals for modifications, inserts or removes.

Comment: The property is already part of a QAbstractListModel... In the background it's just a QStringList, isnt there an easy way using QQmlListProperty?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list there can't be a `propertyChanged()` signal, because the object reference stored will remain the same.
Within the list there won't be properties, so no signal is emitted.

You could instead use a descendent of [`QAbstractListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) which is designed to handle this problem, by wrapping the methods to append, insert etc. in own methods, that then will emit a `dataChanged` signal that carries the information necessary to find the changes.

Of course you could implement something similar yourself by wrapping a `QList` in another object, that has a signal that will inform you of the data change. However this won't integrate that nicely with QML as a real model, for at least view will update automatically, when the `dataChanged` signal is received, and they even only update what is necessary.

Not so, if the `model` of the `View` is changed directly, as might happen, if you manually call `modelChanged()`. In this case, the `View` would miss the information about the changed parts, so it will just recreate itself completely.

Comment: If I should use a model instead, then what's the purpose of a `QQmlListProperty` then? Does it only make sense if the data is modified from Qml only?

Comment: Or another more important question for my project: how can I remove items at all? There is only a clear and an append method defined...

Comment: Yes for me it only makes sense when defining a new QML type from c++ and you want it to have a list property that you populate from QML. Like Item's `states` property

Comment: You are right. I was in a haste yesterday, delete is not possible. As *GrecKo* already explained: The usecase is not the one of an array to alter all the time, but to allow to assign multiple objects. One example are the `states` of each `Item`. Also the `ListModel` uses as `QQmlListProperty` to store the initially declaratively assigned model entries. Compared to a `var` you can enforce certain types (`ListModel` -> `ListElement`) and it is much simpler to handle than a `QJSValue` on the C++-side.

Comment: @derM actually I think the ListModel uses a `QQmlCustomParser` to populate a `QAbstractListModel` which means it is not possible to copy its approach :( because the custom parser is not in public API

Comment: @MarkCh, that sounds interesting to look into! Thank you for that hint!